# It is correct and formal to include "of" when writing dates?

Tags: grammar, dates

A friend of mine, native EN speaker, told me that the following is correct written like this:

> We met on the 1st of June.

Is that really true? I cannot see any reference that these are used in written text.

Comment: I have to wonder how exactly you went about researching written text, as [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+1st+of+june&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the+1st+of+june%22&safe=off&tbm=bks), [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=26889998), and [BNC](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=the+1st+of+June&mysubmit=Go) all have hits for "the 1st of June". That is, *for that precise date*, even. Never mind other dates.

Answer (score 5):

Using 'of' is the standard form in Britain and those countries who speak the Queen's English. In spoken form 'the sixteenth of July' is used as frequently as 'July the sixteenth'. What we don't say in Britain is 'July sixteen'.

When writing we do not include 'of' nor 'the'. But a lot of people, me included, place 'th', 'st', 'nd'  or 'rd' after the digits. e.g. 16th July, 22nd August, 1st March, 23rd April, 21st November etc.

Britain conforms to writing the short form of the date using the European method, which is used throughout almost the entire world except in the United States, i.e. day/month/year. so that 3/5/13 means 3rd May 2013, not 5th March 2013. I have heard it said that the US military follows the standard international method. If that be the case I can only think that it must lead to considerable confusion.

Comment: The "standard international method" is 2013-11-26 in every country in the world except North Korea, but is generally used only in cases where a standard method is necessary. The conventions are much wider than the two you list, such as "2013/11/26" in Japan or even just among English speakers that's also found in South Africa while "26-11-2013" is found in India. And not everyone even in the same country will follow the same convention. Differences on whether to include a leading zero or not, go even further.

Comment: That may be the standard for electronic purposes, ticketing etc. But I am talking about what people write at the tops of letters on cheques, and in everyday communications. The world over, from Japan and China, India, all across Europe the scheme is 26/11/13.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of different date forms used whether in full or contraction.

This is certainly one of them. It's very common in Britain and Ireland, and rarer in the US, though it will be found there.

This matches the common short hand conventions, "the 1<sup>st</sup> of June" matching the "01/06" or "1/6" most common in Britain and Ireland, and "June 1<sup>st</sup>" matching the "06/01" or "6/1" most common in the US.

Note that in the US, it is common to speak of their Independence day as being "the 4<sup>th</sup> of July" or the spelt out as "the fourth of July" or even capitalised to make it a title, "the Fourth of July". This is a legacy of that form being once the more common form in the US, and leaving its mark on the name of the holiday, despite the fact that the "Fourth of July" comes between "July third" and "July fifth"!

Answer (score -1):

It's fine and definitely more formal than saying, "We met on June 1st." It is a little old-fashioned, however.

Comment: But mind you this is about written form. I know when speaking, "the" and "of" are not dropped.

Comment: I see. My answer applies to US English. UK English may be different.

Comment: I don't see what is 'old fashioned' about it. It is perfectly accepted modern English.

Comment: @WS2 it was once more common in the US (hence their still talking of "the Fourth of July") than it is now, so it could well sound old-fashioned to speakers of such dialects.